# Networking failed to start on Alpine linux

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, alpine-linux

I keep getting an error when booting Alpine Linux `Networking failed to start`. I'm using a RPI3 which is connected by an ethernet cable to the box. Here's the `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.255
```

when typing `netstat -r` I have :

```
Destination   Gateway   Genmask         Flags MSS Window irtt Iface
192.168.1.0    *        255.2555.255.0  U       0 0         0 eth0
```

I turned it into dhcp and it worked. Any ideas as to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gateway is wrong.
With the subnet mask you are using, the gateway is not a valid ip address.
Once you get the ip address via DHCP, run:

```
route -n | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

And put that as gateway.
Of course, the "address" entry should be different from the gateway.